# Limit $\lim_{x \to 0 }\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$?

Tags: limits

I have a question regarding limits.

Recently in a math class, my teacher states that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ goes to $1$ hence in the case of a $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}$, the answer is $1$.

Why is that so? Shouldn't the answer be $0$ in this case?

Comment: Two important points: $\qquad(1)$ The most important reason for introducing limits in calculus is to deal with cases where the numerator and denominator both approach $0$. If the limit were always $0$ in such cases, then derivatives would always be $0$. $\qquad(2)$ This result and some others like it are correct ONLY if _radians_ are used, rather than degrees or some other units, and that's the major reason why radian measure is important in calculus. The derivative of sine is a constant time cosine, and the constant is $1$ only if radians are used. (If degrees are used, then it's $\pi/180$.)

Comment: It might be useful to explain why you think the answer should be 0.

Comment: You might draw a chart of x / sin x near zero just using data from a pocket calculator, and then explain what you think the limit is.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $\dfrac{x}{\sin x}  = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Look up the squeeze theorem or L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule gives quick answers but not insight, and what's worse: this limit is used in _proving_ that $(d/dx)\sin x=\cos x$, which is then used when L'Hopital's rule is applied to this problem, so there is a logically fallacious circular argument. $\qquad$

Comment: You're right--I had not considered that here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. One which may help shed light on "why" the limit tends to 1 is that for $x \approx 0$ $$\sin(x) \approx x.$$ You can see this with the Taylor series expansion of sine.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to JLA for pointing this out.

You may also verify this by graphing the sine function for inputs close to 0 and observing that the graph looks linear with slope 1.

Comment: How does one derive the taylor series for sine without already knowing this fact?

Comment: @JLA To derive this Taylor series you need to know $sin(0) = 0$ and $cos(0) = 1$ and the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives of sine (which the OP admittedly probably  doesn't know at this point). However, this was mostly for a  reasonably accessible theoretical basis for the claim.

Comment: @JLA Although I still agree with your concern and I've edited the reply to reflect this. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you stated you know, namely that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, I think what you are missing is the following property of limits.

If $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exist, and moreover $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) \neq 0$ then $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{ \lim_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a} g(x)}.$$

In your case, $g(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}, f(x) = 1$, and $a=0$ (as @Kf_Sansoo pointed out in their answer).